# dead code warning in the i++ part in the for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, dead-code

This code keeps giving me a dead code warning on the `i++` in the for loop and it is not incrementing the `i` for some reason!

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HideThatNumber {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int enc=input.nextInt();
        int tur=0;
        String test="";
        double x;
        for (int i=1;i<10;i++){
            test="";
            test+=i;
            test+=enc;
            x=Integer.parseInt(test);
            x/=11;
            if(x==Math.round(x));{
                tur=i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(tur==0)
            System.out.println("Impossible");
        else 
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(test)/11);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
    if(x==Math.round(x)); <--semi-colon
    {
        tur=i;
        break;
    }
```

Inside your for loop, you have put a semi-colon at the end of your `if`. Thus the next `block` of code will be executed in any case, and thus you would break out of your loop after the first iteration.

```
    {
        tur=i;
        break;
    }
```

This block will be executed regardless of what your if condition evaluate to. And you `break` out of the loop.

And hence you get the warning, because `i++` will never be executed.

Comment: +1 your answer came just as i spotted the error. Question: Is a codeblock inside curly brackets whithin a method really called initializer block? I don't know how to call them, but I thought initializer block is inside a class definition.

Comment: YEs, they are initializer block. I also thought earlier that we can have them only in the class, but few days back I came to know this.

Comment: Actually, when we declare and initialize out instance variable outside a constructor, then the compiler puts that initialization code inside an initializer block in every constructor. And that's when I came to know that, rather we can have them inside any block.

Comment: @RohitJain That's not at all correct. A plain block inside a method is not an initializer block, since it's not initializing anything - it's not run as part of the constructor as initializer blocks would be. It's just a regular "block" that gets executed in sequence, and besides scoping local variables doesn't have much use.

Comment: @millimoose. But I read it somewhere, that the initiazation code is shifted to an `initializer block` in the constructor?? Is it wrong?

Comment: @RohitJain It is for initialiser blocks. Those are plain blocks that appear *in the body of the class*. (Meaning, **not** inside methods.) Plain blocks that are inside methods aren't shifted anywhere and thus are not initialiser blocks.

Comment: @millimoose. Ok. Got it. And updated post accordingly. Thanks for information. AT first I was also surprised on reading that. I guess I got my wrong information corrected now. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's this line:

```
if(x==Math.round(x)); {
```

The semicolon shouldn't be there. In your code, the block with the `break;` always gets executed - so it breaks after the first iteration.